# How to find minimum value of a column imported from Excel using MATLAB

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, matrix, min

I have a set of values in the following pattern.

```
A   B   C   D
1   5   6   11
2   6   5   21
3   7   3   42
4   3   7   22
1   2   3   54
2   3   2   43
3   4   3   27
4   3   2   14
```

I exported the every column into MATLAB workspace as follows.

```
A = xlsread('F:\R.xlsx','Complete Data','A2:A43'); 
B = xlsread('F:\R.xlsx','Complete Data','B2:B43'); 
C = xlsread('F:\R.xlsx','Complete Data','C2:C43'); 
D = xlsread('F:\R.xlsx','Complete Data','D2:D43');
```

I need help with code where the it has to check the Column A, find the lowest D value and output the corresponding B and C values. I need the output to look like.

```
1   5   6   11
2   6   5   21
3   4   3   27
4   3   2   14
```

I read through related questions and understand that I need to make it a matrix and sort it based on the element on the 4th column using

### sortrows

and get indices of the sorted elements. But I am stuck here. Please Guide me.

Comment: What happened to `22` in D? Anyway, try `fliplr(sortrows([D C B A]))`

Comment: It arranges the D column in the order from minimum number to maximum. Thanks much. I can go ahead with that. Is there anyway to only select one row value for one A number. For example, if we consider 4 from A, it has values, 3 7 22 and 3 2 14. So Can I only get the output of 4 3 2 14 ignoring the other because D is minimum in that? @Adiel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can export those columns in one go as:

   ```
   ABCD = xlsread('F:\R.xlsx','Complete Data','A2:D43');
   ```
2. Now use `sortrows` to sort the rows according to the first and the fourth column.

   ```
   req = sortrows(ABCD, [1 4]);
   ```
3. ☆ If all elements of the first column exist twice then:

   ```
   req = req(1:2:end,:);
   ```

   ☆ If it is not necessary that all elements of the first column will exist twice then:

   ```
   [~, ind] = unique(req(:,1));
   req =  req(ind,:);
   ```

Comment: This is clever. `unique` finds the first element with each unique value, and since they're sorted on D, the first value is the one with the lowest D value. Nice!